# Calling C printf from assembly

Tags: c, nasm

I would like to call the printf function from C with two integers.
My format string is:

```
LC0:
    db "odd bits: %d, even bits: %d", 10, 0
```

I have the integer ob and eb:

```
ob: DD 0
eb: DD 0
```

and then I do at the end:

```
push dword [ob]
push dword [eb]
push LC0
call printf
add esp,8
```

However, this gives me the result `Odd bits: [ob], Even bits: [ob, repeated]` then gives me a segmentation fault.
Am I calling the `printf` function wrong?

EDIT:
I added `LC1` as `db "even bits: %d", 10 0`, then redid:

```
push dword [ob]
push LC0
call printf
push dword [eb]
push LC1
call printf
add esp, 8
```

This gives me a REVERSED result, giving the eb to the LC0 string, and ob to the LC1 string, and, it gives a segmentation fault at the end.
Any clue?

Comment: This is not the problem, but you should push `eb` first, then `ob`, since you want to push the parameters from right to left.

Comment: I fixed the reversed result, it is the original code, but I merely forgot to relink (sorry...)
The seg fault still exists, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adjusting the stack pointer correctly.

In your original code you were pushing 12 bytes, but only "popping" 8.

In your updated code you're pushing 8 bytes twice, i.e. 16 bytes in total, but only "popping" 8 bytes once.

---

As for the order in which the values are printed; in your original code you had:

```
push dword [ob]  
push dword [eb]
push LC0
```

You've declared `LC0` as `db "odd bits: %d, even bits: %d", 10, 0`, so clearly you intended `ob` to the printed first. Arguments are push right-to-left, so you should push `eb` before `ob`.

Comment: Please see edit on the new result. This comes out because I am a newbie in the c-assmelby interaction. How do I correct this?

Comment: Your edit is what I refer to as "your updated code". I'm talking about the segfault here, not the order of the values you get.

Comment: Works!
Did not realize that the `add esp, 8` is actually `popping` so that assembly can go on and finish itself.
I re-put only 1 format string, and pushed in reverse, and popped 12 (eb, ob and lc0).

Much appreciated!