# Why is there a segmentation fault in this simple x86-64 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I wrote this just to print out an integer, why am I getting a segmentation fault? (Using the gnu assembler)

```
.extern printf
.data 
n: .long 12345
.text
.global _start

_start:
xorq %rax, %rax
movq n, %rdi
call printf

movq $60, %rax      # syscall number for exit
xor %rdi, %rdi      # status 0
syscall             # call kernel
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault. Also-- am I also meant to set %rsi to something or is that just for syscalls? Also I always link it with gcc so extern is not the issue.
I've also tried  changing n to  n: .string "12345\n\0" but it still gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: Your stack alignment is likely incorrect.  Also, the libc has not been initialised as you don't go through the C runtime stub, so printf may do unexpected things.

Comment: @fuz by stack alignment -- you mean changing the %rbp and %rsp? is it necessary? and how do i fix the libc bug then? i thought i'm just meant to write .extern (and when i  link it i write gcc -nostartfiles -no-pie -o testing testing.o)

Comment: `printf` expects a format string as first argument. You can not do `printf(12345)` you should do `printf("%d\n", 12345)` Also note that `.long` is 32 bits.

Comment: @fuz: Stack alignment *is* correct, assuming this is assembled + linked into a Linux executable: `_start` isn't a function, the ABI guarantees that `RSP % 16 == 0` at the top of `_start`.  Unlike for functions where `RSP % 16 == 8` because the `call` itself pushed a return address.  Initializing libc is a valid concern, but the OP's `gcc` command will produce a dynamically-linked executable.  Glibc uses libc hooks to get itself initialized even without `_start` calling any functions.  So it's just the bug Jester pointed out.

Comment: With `.asciz "12345\n"` or the equivalent `.string`, you need `mov $n, %edi` or `lea n(%rip), %rdi` to put the address in a register, not load 8 bytes of ASCII data into a register.  The C equivalent of your code with `.string` would be `char *ptr;`  `memcpy(&ptr, "12345\n", 8);` `printf(ptr);` which of course faults on the invalid pointer when printf tries to dereference it.  You can see in GDB which instruction faults: it'll be inside `printf`.

Comment: [Linking and calling printf from gas assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66808859) shows correct code to call printf from `_start`, which will work the way you're linking (into a non-PIE executable).